# Figuring out the size of an InputStream

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I'm currently getting an input stream using Amazon's S3 storage like below:

```
public static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String fileKey) {
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
    return s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileKey)).getObjectContent();
}
```

The files I'm dealing with are .mp4 videos. I'm attempting to stream the video using Range-Requests to allow for fast forwarding and rewinding for the end user. My streaming was working fine when I was using regular `File` objects, but now I'm receiving a stream from Amazon S3 instead of using a file saved on a local machine.

How can I figure out the length of this stream? Before, I did this:

```
Long length = Files.size(filepath);
```

But now this does not work as I do not have a file saved directly on the machine running the Java code. Is there any way to figure out the length of the `InputStream`?

Comment: No. `InputStream` is a stream of bytes, the only way to know the size is to read until no more bytes are returned.

Comment: @Kayaman So I should read the `InputStream` and store the bytes in a byte array until no more bytes are returned, then check the size of the byte array?

Comment: Not usually no. That would be wast an incredible amount of memory, so usually you need to design around it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't get the length of an InputStream unless you read it from start to end and count the number of bytes you've read yourself.

You can get the length of an [S3Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3Object.html) though:

```
public static InputStream getResourceAsStream(String fileKey) {
    AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
    S3Object obj = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, fileKey));
    long length = obj.getObjectMetadata().getInstanceLength();
    //use length
    return obj.getObjectContent();
}
```